# asp.net openxml open docx, change content and stream to user

Tags: asp.net, ms-word, openxml

My code is below. I'm trying to open a Word document with Open XML and change certain text. The document must then be send to the client where they can save it on their PC or Open it. It send a document to the client but it is blank. When I save my InMemory document it says the file cannot be open it must contain at least one root element. I'm using Visual STudio 2010 Express. Please help me. What is wrong with my code?

```
   Dim fileName As String = "directory on server\doc.docx"

    Dim myDocument As WordprocessingDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(fileName, True)

    Dim docText As String = Nothing

    Dim sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(myDocument.MainDocumentPart.GetStream)
    docText = sr.ReadToEnd
    sr.Close()

    Dim regexText As Regex = New Regex("XXXCourtXXX")
    docText = regexText.Replace(docText, "JOHANNESBURG")

    Dim ms As New MemoryStream()
    Dim sw As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(ms)

    sw.Write(docText)
    myDocument.MainDocumentPart.FeedData(ms)

    Dim mem = New MemoryStream()
    myDocument.MainDocumentPart.GetStream().CopyTo(Response.OutputStream)
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=Notice.docx")
    mem.Position = 0
    mem.CopyTo(Response.OutputStream)
    Response.Flush()
    Response.End()
```

Answer (score 0):

You're dimming a new memory stream mem, writing nothing to it and then copying it to the output stream. Remove all lines referencing your mem variable.

Comment: myDocument.MainDocumentPart.FeedData(ms) seems to close the ms memory stream. If I remove all the mems memory stream and replace it with my first memory stream it gives me the following message: Cannot access a closed Stream.

Comment: I don't understand why you replaced mem with ms? why is mem even there you're not doing anything with it.